# On the tagging of events and event handling

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request

***Note:*** This was going to be a simple tag merge request, but it grew while I was researching it.

On Stack Overflow, [event-handler](/questions/tagged/event-handler) has 24 questions, [eventhandler](/questions/tagged/eventhandler) 20, and [event-handlers](/questions/tagged/event-handlers) 12. This seems unnecessary.

The reason I bring it up on Meta is that I'm not sure which should be the canonical tag. [event-handler](/questions/tagged/event-handler) seems more logical, but [eventhandler](/questions/tagged/eventhandler) might be the way it appears in code.

And how should this tag be used with the [events](/questions/tagged/events) [1549], [event](/questions/tagged/event) [360], [handler](/questions/tagged/handler) [56], [handling](/questions/tagged/handling) [41], [handlers](/questions/tagged/handlers) [12], and [event-handling](/questions/tagged/event-handling) [514] tags? And what about [javascript-events](/questions/tagged/javascript-events) [509]? I was going to ask a question about JavaScript event handlers, which is how I got mixed up in this in the first place. What tags would I use?

Note that I don't think that the `handl*` tags should be merged with `event*` tags, since there are other kinds of handlers (error-handlers come to mind).

Answer (score 4):

Wow, what a mess! Touching these before the black list is enabled is a waste of time. The tags will be added again.

I vote for `event-handlers`. We normally use the plural form, don't we?

The questions tagged both `hand*` and `event` should be retagged to `event-handlers` then.

Comment: Are you suggesting that the [javascript-]event[s] tags be merged with the [event[-]]handler[s|ing] tags? They're not quite the same thing...

Comment: The tag blacklist, like the global rep recalc, is a myth.

Comment: @Shog: Nope, I have no opinion regarding to the `javascript-events`. I do not know enough about javascript, so I really don't care.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to see `javascript-events` merged with `events` and `event`.

No idea what to do about `*handl*`... But there are few enough questions that you could conceivably examine each one individually.

Answer (score 0):

I was about to write a similar question, when I found this one and [eventhandler] vs [event-handler] vs [event-handlers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49400/eventhandler-vs-event-handler-vs-event-handlers).

Currently, there is [event-handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/event-handling) (859), [event-handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/event-handler) (30) and [event-handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/event-handlers) (19).  I would propose all three be moved into the first.

Also, I would suggest [dom-events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dom-events) (4) be merged into [javascript-events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-events) (1197), even though one may argue dom-events is more correct for some questions.

Lastly, these all seem like candidate for tag synonyms to avoid future splits.