# Merge the tags [javascript], [javascript-events] and [javascript-library]

Tags: support, tag-synonyms, retag-request

Can these tags be merged?

[javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) [javascript-library](/questions/tagged/javascript-library) [javascript-events](/questions/tagged/javascript-events)

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33023/on-the-tagging-of-events-and-event-handling

Answer (score 4):

No, they're not the same.

But I agree that we should get rid of [javascript-events](/questions/tagged/javascript-events) in favor of [events](/questions/tagged/events), and [javascript-libraries](/questions/tagged/javascript-libraries) should be thrown into the pit.

Answer (score 2):

Why merge [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) and [javascript-events](/questions/tagged/javascript-events)? It looks like the latter is about a pretty well-defined subset of the more general [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript).

Personally I think [javascript-events](/questions/tagged/javascript-events) has some valid uses.

[javascript-library](/questions/tagged/javascript-library) seems to be used a bit less consistently. I see it used *mostly* on two kinds of questions:

- questions *about* a *specific* JavaScript library. In this case it's not useful, as they *usually* have the concrete library tag as well (and should have it if they don't).
- questions about finding a JavaScript library for some specific use case (or worse: "which of those is better?").